# Bing Ads - Search network bid (GBP)?

Tags: advertising, bing

I am setting up my first Bing Ads for my site but ran into a input box i don't understand:

Search network bid (GBP)

Can anyone explain this and what sort of amount should i input?

Would something like £0.05 be too low or maybe even too high?

Comment: Bing can display your advertiser on two ways first on their search network which is bing.com and other through pulibhser who use media.net. When you select any keyword then you will get roughly bid amount suggestion. Set a price to near that, because it is impossible to say weather $0.05 is high or very low.

Answer (score 1):

The search network refers to Bing.com itself and any embedded versions of it. Your bid would then be matched against others who bid on the same keywords/terms and you'd be billed, if the ad was displayed, for the impression of the ad within search results.